# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function in core-js

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce, core-js

I'm trying to install the [BigCommerce Open Checkout](https://medium.com/bigcommerce-developer-blog/bigcommerce-checkout-is-now-open-source-39e823bc5b3b) script, and I'm currently getting this error when I try to run the basic installation locally:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at eval (es.array.index-of.js?c975:15)
at Object../node_modules/core-js/modules/es.array.index-of.js
```

That file is:

```
'use strict';
var $ = require('../internals/export');
var $indexOf = require('../internals/array-includes').indexOf;
var arrayMethodIsStrict = require('../internals/array-method-is-strict');
var arrayMethodUsesToLength = require('../internals/array-method-uses-to-length');

var nativeIndexOf = [].indexOf;

var NEGATIVE_ZERO = !!nativeIndexOf && 1 / [1].indexOf(1, -0) < 0;
var STRICT_METHOD = arrayMethodIsStrict('indexOf');
var USES_TO_LENGTH = arrayMethodUsesToLength('indexOf', { ACCESSORS: true, 1: 0 });

// `Array.prototype.indexOf` method
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.indexof
$({ target: 'Array', proto: true, forced: NEGATIVE_ZERO || !STRICT_METHOD || !USES_TO_LENGTH }, {
  indexOf: function indexOf(searchElement /* , fromIndex = 0 */) {
    return NEGATIVE_ZERO
      // convert -0 to +0
      ? nativeIndexOf.apply(this, arguments) || 0
      : $indexOf(this, searchElement, arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : undefined);
  }
});
```

So far, I've tried updating core-js and NPM repeatedly with no luck.

Comment: What's the export line for ../internals/export

Comment: I would ensure that you're using Node greater than v. 10 but maybe stick to the latest stable version. NPM should be greater than v.3 Have you changed anything in the web pack build process? This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/743) might be helpful. I would also ensure that you are following the build and CI process noted in the [ReadME.md](https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-js).

Comment: @RachaelThompson I've been going over the readme and other related documents for days now. I'm currently using Node v. 14.15.1 and NPM v. 6.14.8, but I tried using a later build of Node v. 10 with no success. I also looked at that GitHub issue but couldn't determine a resolution based on it (my experience with Node is extremely limited).

Comment: @LevKuznetsov I'm not sure what you're asking, but the export.js file it links to does exist and loads correctly.

Comment: @gbroaddus Could you solve the problem?

Comment: @zeekrey I never did solve this, nor did another developer I work with. As it would happen, the project we were trying to do this for ended up having a separate solution.

Answer (score 3):

core-js should not be compiled by Babel. When using webpack + babel to compile your code, you need to ensure that the webpack module rule for babel-loader excludes core-js.

### Option 1

Tell webpack to not use babel-loader for any of the dependencies in your node_modules. Since core-js is a dependency in node_modules, this excludes core-js from being processed by babel.

```js
// webpack.config.js
// This code snippet shows only the relevant part of the webpack config
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?(j|t)sx?$/,
        // Excluding node_modules means that core-js will not be compiled
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Option 2

Tell webpack to compile all dependencies with babel, except for the core-js dependency:

```js
// webpack.config.js
// This code snippet shows only the relevant part of the webpack config
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?(j|t)sx?$/,
        // Compile all node_modules except core-js
        include: {
          and: [/node_modules/],
          not: [/core-js/]
        },
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Relevant Links

- https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/912
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleexclude
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleinclude
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Second time I have been here, I found the solution to this and then forgot, so if for nobody else this is for future me.

From the README https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-js

- Node >= v16
- NPM >= v8.
- Unix-based operating system.

The node version didn't matter for me, v18 was fine, but as I'm on windows I needed to do the npm actions in WSL, it won't work on normal windows.